# CodeIgniter DB Where length?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-clause

I am trying to write a where clause in CodeIgniter that says where length(id) > 17

I tried this out trying to get ids that have a length of under 5 (which are none) excepting no results and the same results came up:

```
$this->db->where('LENGTH(id) <', 5);
```

Help?

Answer (score 2):

you can set escape False as third parameter of where not to protect the where string you can execute sql function in where

```
$this->db->where('LENGTH(id) <', 5, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->where('LENGTH(id)<5', NULL, FALSE);